# ajax before redirect not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

So on click of a link, I want to make an ajax call to a script, but under certain conditions, I also want to redirect the page.  The script runs fine (it pretty much just sets a cookie) when the conditions are not met and the page doesn't redirect, but I suspect what happens when the page does redirect is the ajax doesn't have a chance to hit the script before it redirects.

I can't really afford to have the redirect in a callback on the ajax success as this is a very common function of the site and it will drastically slow down the UX.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

```
$("li").click(function(e) {

        var addressValue = $(this).find('a:first').attr("href");
        var hash_tag = $(this).find('a:first');
        var iframe_header = hash_tag.text();
        var hashValue = hash_tag.attr("id");
        var dest = '/site_client/' + '#' + hashValue;
        alert(dest);
        alert(iframe_header);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/site_client/set_redirect_back/",
            data: {redirect_back: dest, redirect_back_page_name: iframe_header},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"

        });
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("site_client") === -1) {

            window.location.href = dest;
            e.preventDefault();

         }else{

            $('#iframe1').hide();
            var spinner = $('#loading-spinner');
            $(spinner).show();

            $('#tool-header').text(iframe_header);

            location.hash = hashValue;
            document.getElementById('iframe1').src = addressValue;
            e.preventDefault();

        }

    });
```

Comment: you need to add your redirect code to the callback function of your ajax call ... ie `success: function(data){ your code here }`

Comment: that's to be expected. (A)synchronos (j)avascript (a)nd (x)ml. You fire off the ajax call, then the redirect kicks in nearly immediately, which SHUTS DOWN the current page, including the ajax request.

Comment: Ok, thanks, yeah that is what I thought, just wondering if there is a way to achieve that without using a callback.

Comment: well, you could use `async: false`, this is the single situation where there is no *good* alternative to `async: false`. using `async: true` (the default) here means you either have to re-implement default behavior or remove it (such as being unable to open 
in a new tab.) I usually try to avoid this situation all together by doing the redirect logic server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Call your JavaScript in success callback:

```js
$("li").click(function(e) {
    var addressValue = $(this).find('a:first').attr("href");
    var hash_tag = $(this).find('a:first');
    var iframe_header = hash_tag.text();
    var hashValue = hash_tag.attr("id");
    var dest = '/site_client/' + '#' + hashValue;
    alert(dest);
    alert(iframe_header);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/site_client/set_redirect_back/",
        data: {redirect_back: dest, redirect_back_page_name: iframe_header},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("site_client") === -1) {

                window.location.href = dest;
                e.preventDefault();

             }else{

                $('#iframe1').hide();
                var spinner = $('#loading-spinner');
                $(spinner).show();

                $('#tool-header').text(iframe_header);

                location.hash = hashValue;
                document.getElementById('iframe1').src = addressValue;
                e.preventDefault();

            }
        }
    });
});
```